# Why is the browser not sending cookies with cross-domain WebSocket handshake request?

Tags: csrf, cors, websocket, same-site-cookies

If I have understood Cross-Site WebSocket Hijacking (CSWSH) attack correctly [1][2][3][4], the attack relies on two things (examples are from the first reference):

- the browser sending the cookies set by the victim domain (`www.some-trading-application.com`) over a WebSocket handshake request initiated from a JavaScript code running on the attacker domain (`https://www.some-evil-attacker-application.com`)
- no `Origin` header check being performed on the victim server side

The first happens due to the absence (by design) of cross-origin checks for WebSocket requests. I tested the hypothesis with a [demo app](https://ufile.io/gecfv5d4) that I developed. While the browser (Firefox 102.8.0esr (64-bit)) does permit cross-origin WebSocket requests, it does not send the `auth_cookie` cookie alongwith. For my test setup, I did the following:

- Pointed both `victim.com` and `attacker.com` to `127.0.0.1` by modifying `/etc/hosts` on a Ubuntu system
- Victim web app (which includes the WebSocket server, too) runs on `victim.com:5000`, and sets an `auth_cookie` with the most relaxed restrictions (`HttpOnly=False`, `Secure=False`, `SameSite=None`, `Path=/`)
- Attacker webpage runs on `attacker.com:10000`, and initiates a WebSocket handshake to `victim.com:5000/logincheck`, the vulnerable WebSocket endpoint. I made sure that the `auth_cookie` is set in the browser by `victim.com` before the WebSocket call is made from `attacker.com`.

Unfortunately, I could not see the `auth_cookie` being sent either from developer tools in the browser, or Burp proxy. I repeated the test with other Firefox and Chrome versions as well, but had the same result.

Does CSWSH even work on modern browsers?

### References

1. https://christian-schneider.net/CrossSiteWebSocketHijacking.html
2. https://infosecwriteups.com/cross-site-websocket-hijacking-cswsh-ce2a6b0747fc
3. https://snyk.io/blog/gitpod-remote-code-execution-vulnerability-websockets
4. https://github.com/carlospolop/hacktricks/blob/master/pentesting-web/cross-site-websocket-hijacking-cswsh.md

Comment: Did you consider in your tests that modern browsers by default restrict the scope of a cookie, so that it cannot be used cross-site unless explicitly defined by the server setting the cookie? See  [SameSite attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#samesitesamesite-value).  So you would need to use `SameSite=None` (which requires use of `Secure` attribute which then means to use TLS, i.e. HTTPS/WSS)

Comment: I had the same suspicion, too. However, I already mentioned that I tested with `SameSite=None`. See my post above.

Comment: Do you use HTTPS though when setting the cookie? `Secure=False` suggests not and is apart from that not a valid cookie attribute (there is only `Secure`, nothing with true or false). To cite from what I linked to: *"Note: A Secure cookie is only sent to the server with an encrypted request over the HTTPS protocol. Note that insecure sites (http:) can't set cookies with the Secure directive, and therefore can't use SameSite=None."*

Comment: Sorry. Writing `Secure=False` wasn't probably the best way to indicate that the cookie is *not* secure, and therefore can be sent over HTTP, which is what I used throughout the test.

Comment: FYI, I linked the demo app in my post in case you or anyone else wants to play with it

Comment: So the problems seems to be that you were trying to set `SameSite=None` with plain HTTP - which does not work as documented (and cited). This means the attribute is ignored and the cookie will not work cross-site. Not a problem of CSWSH no longer working but of your test setup.

Comment: I am not sure if `therefore can't use SameSite=None` part is true. I can confirm that `auth_cookie` is set correctly, and in fact, be retrieved from another endpoint (`http://victim.com:5000/getcookie`). Interestingly, I can see the demo working in Firefox v65.0, but not with the latest one (v114).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147073/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-sherlock).

Answer (score 3):

The browser is not respecting the `SameSite=None` flag, because the cookie is not `Secure` (and can't be, since it wasn't set via a secure context). [MDN claims that the expected behavior is to reject such cookies outright](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#samesitesamesite-value), but browsers that aren't fully compliant with the current spec might do things like "ignore the SameSite flag and use the default value" (which has been "Lax" for some years now).

If you go to the dev tools in the browser and look at the list of cookies for the site (in Firefox's dev tools, this is under the "Storage" tab), what shows up? Is the cookie listed as SameSite: None, or some other value? (Is it there at all?) Also, when setting the cookie, do any errors appear in the console? MDN says that an error message should be logged.

A browser old enough to not support SameSite at all, or to not care whether the cookie is Secure or not when considering SameSite, will not run into this problem and will exhibit the vulnerability with your current app. For a modern browser, run the server (for both sites) on HTTPS and make the cookie Secure (and SameSite=None), and the browser should exhibit the vulnerability.